# How to suppress the "match may not be exhaustive" warning in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am currently implementing a small internally used utility that imports data from a set of Excel files to our application. Based on the type of the Excel cell, I decide how to treat the data. The Excel file can contain only string, numeric and Boolean cells, if any other cell is encountered, the program is free to crash at run-time.

Now Scala is correctly warning me that the match on the cell type is not exhaustive, the cells can have the type of blank, formula, error...

Is there a way how to suppress the warning, except the obvious one?:

```
t match {
  case STRING => ???
  case NUMERIC => ???
  case BOOLEAN => ???
  case _ => throw new MatchError() // redundant, just to suppress the compile time warning
}
```

Comment: The canonical question has a highly specific question and answer. This question is more general and should not be considered a duplicate. If anything, the linked question needs to be edited.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the [unchecked](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/unchecked.html) annotation:

```
(t: @unchecked) match {
  case STRING => ???
  case NUMERIC => ???
  case BOOLEAN => ???
}
```

As others have mentioned, you should avoid using it and instead choose your types accordingly to avoid such warnings (e.g. by using sealed traits). If, however, you find yourself unable to do so, and you have some kind of invariant that guarantees that your type is always one of the given types, using `@unchecked` solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew that there was some annotation, but I never used it so I have forgotten if really and which one :)
I agree with you that it should be avoided. In this case however the excel I need to process might contain "invalid" cells, so the types are not for me to define. And if the excel is invalid (for my programs purpose) I want the program to crash with a run time exception. So the annotation is perfect here :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not recommended (for usual cases), but if you really need it, use `PartialFuncion`:

```
sealed trait Trait
case object A extends Trait
case object B extends Trait


scala>   def f(x: Trait) = x match {
 |     case A => println("A")
 |   }
<console>:13: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: B
         def f(x: Trait) = x match {
                           ^
f: (x: Trait)Unit


scala> val f: PartialFunction[Trait, Unit] = {
 |     case A => println("A")
 |   }
f: PartialFunction[Trait,Unit] = <function1>

scala> f(A)
A

scala> f(B)
scala.MatchError: B (of class B$)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:254)
  at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:252)
  at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:14)
  at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:13)
  at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:34)
  ... 29 elided
```

The disadvantage of partial functions is that they create a risk of runtime exception. But they're more safe than `@unchecked` approach (should be used in extreme cases) - at least user can see potential exception from the type itself.

In your case I'd recommend you to use `Option` and separate logic from effects:

```
  def f(x: Trait) = x match {
    case A => Some("A")
    case _ => None
  }

  def effect(x: Option[String]) = x.foreach(println) //you can use getOrElse(throw RuntimeException) here

  def run(x: Trait) = effect(f(x))

scala> run(A)
A

scala> run(B)
```